# pyqt relational table not updating when foreign key is updated

Tags: python, sqlite, model-view-controller, pyqt4, qsqltablemodel

I have a window with a splitter, inside the two frames there are two different tables, and the product type has a relation with product and the GUI runs and works fine but when I change a name on product type it doesn't update on the product table, why is that? but once i restart the changes are made? is there a way to force pyqt model to check the database for changes?

```
def initUI(self):

        self.connectDb()

        mainlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.mode = QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection

        self.topleft = QtGui.QFrame(self)
        self.topleft.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.topleftfill()
        self.topright = QtGui.QFrame(self)
        self.topright.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.toprightfill()

        splittertop = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        splittertop.addWidget(self.topleft)
        splittertop.addWidget(self.topright)
        mainlayout.addWidget(splittertop)
        self.setLayout(mainlayout)

def topleftfill(self):
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
    model = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
    model.setTable("Product")
    model.setRelation(6, QtSql.QSqlRelation("ProductType","ProductTypeID","Type"))
    model.select()
    model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Product ID")
    model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Product Name")
    model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "In Stock ")
    model.setHeaderData(3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Expiry Date")
    model.setHeaderData(4, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Stock Alert")
    model.setHeaderData(5, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Price")
    model.setHeaderData(6, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Product Type")
    edit = QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange
    model.setEditStrategy(edit)
    view = QtGui.QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.setSelectionMode(self.mode)
    view.setItemDelegate(QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate(view))
    layout.addWidget(view)
    self.topleft.setLayout(layout)

def toprightfill(self):
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
    model = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
    model.setTable("ProductType")
    model.select()
    model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Product Type ID")
    model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Product Type")
    edit = QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange
    model.setEditStrategy(edit)
    view = QtGui.QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.setSelectionMode(self.mode)
    layout.addWidget(view)
    self.topright.setLayout(layout)


def connectDb(self):
    name = 'PostOffice.db'
    initDb.setup_database(name)
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName(name)
    if not db.open():
        print("Cannot Connect")
        return False
```

Comment: I never used a `QSqlRelationalTableModel` but maybe you should emit the `dataChanged` signal (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) when data is changed in your model. This is how it works for table models for example.

Comment: I'm kind of confused, do you know how to write that in python? or could you give me an example?

Comment: I deleted my answer below since it is not working. I am pretty sure, this has to do with the `dataChanged` signal. Try to find something regarding this and your `QSqlRelationalTableModel`. Good luck!

Comment: I have found out why :) thanks

Comment: Glad to read that you found an answer :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is once your button has been pressed to edit changes if your using the `OnManualSubmit` edit strategy, you need make sure you repopulate your table by calling the `model.select()` function otherwise the program will use your old model until you restart the program